# VBA Lotus DB Search - Get folder/view name of current document

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-domino

i am trying to write a VBA code to search Lotus DB based on keywords and then extract the results details into another Sheet.

Although i am able to pull multiple fields as needed, i would also need the 'Folder' name / View name to which the current document belongs to. I have tried searching for all available fields but still unable to find any. Any help please?

```
Set notesdb = NotesSession.getDatabase(Servr, Dbase)
DteTime = ((DateAdd("n", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("E15").Value, Now())))

If notesdb.IsOpen = True Then
    'Already open for mail
Else
    notesdb.OPENMAIL
End If

Set GlobalCollection = notesdb.Search("@Created > [" & DteTime & "] " & " & @Contains(" & "Subject" & ";" & """" & Subjct & """" & ")", Nothing, 0)

Set AllDocc = GlobalCollection.GetFirstDocument

While Not (AllDocc Is Nothing)
    LastRow = Sht.Cells(Sht.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    roww = LastRow + 1
    Sht.Range("A" & roww) = AllDocc.GetItemValue("SendTo")(0)  
wend
```

Answer (score 2):

This information is not easily available. A folder / view KNOWS which documents it contains, but a document does not know in which folder / view it is shown.

A document can be in many folders and views. One single mail can be in multiple folders, will allways be shown in „all documents“ view and if it was sent it will eb shown in „Sent“ view. If you enable a followup it will be in the followup view as well...

There are multiple ways to get that information: you could run through all views, then through all documents in them and then check if your document belongs , then remember the names of all folders / views the document is in.

OR you could enable „Folderreferences“ in the database. Then each document will contain the UNIVERSALID of every folder it belongs to, you just need to assign these UNIDS to readable foldernames. Unfortunately this feature does not work for documents that were put in the folders BEFORE the property had been enabled... not a perfekt match either...

So: unfortunately this is not done easily and needs a lot of code to write, and even more code, to do it quick for many documents...